# Error with CAPM.beta.bear and TimingRatio in PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

When I run the code below, my function for CAPM.beta.bull works correctly, but returns an error for both CAPM.beta.bear and TimingRatio

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL", from="2012-01-01", to="2015-01-01")
getSymbols("SPY", from="2012-01-01", to="2015-01-01")


stockbull = function(call){
CAPM.beta.bull(Ad(call), Ad(SPY) , Rf=0)
}

stockbear = function(call){
CAPM.beta.bear(Ad(call), Ad(SPY), Rf=0)
}

stocktiming = function(call){
TimingRatio(Ad(call), Ad(SPY) , Rf=0)
}
```

I am running R 3.1.3 and here is my resulting error, any help would be much appreciated.

```
> stockbull(AAPL)
[1] 0.3041228
> stockbear(AAPL)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
> stocktiming(AAPL)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the PerformanceAnalytics functions use stock returns, not prices so you need to first compute returns and then pass to these functions.  For example, your stockbull function could become

```
stockbull = function(call){
  Ra <- Return.calculate(Ad(call))
  Rb <- Return.calculate(Ad(SPY))
  CAPM.beta.bull(Ra, Rb , Rf=0)
}
```

with very similar changes for the other functions.  With these modifications, the CAPM.beta functions return values close to 1. which are reasonable results.